# Why can't my Adobe Photoshop CS5 read RAW photos saved in .NEF from my new camera?

Tags: raw, nikon-d3100, photoshop-cs5

My Nikon D3100 photos are not coming up on photoshop why I try to edit them. What should I do?

Comment: According to Adobe, as of ACR 6.3 (current latest), the D3100 is supported. I would be surprised, otherwise, since both the Pentax K-5 and Nikon D7000 are also supported and are slightly newer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Upgraded from a comment, since it's really an answer.)

Have you updated Adobe Camera Raw? Run Adobe Application Manager; the D3100 is a fairly new camera and it's likely that your version of ACR doesn't support it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade Adobe Camera RAW (it will be free). If that doesn't work, get Adobe DNG Convertor, also free, which converts NEF to DNG, a 'universal' RAW format.

Answer (score 0):

Addition:

Link: [Adobe DNG Converter Homepage](http://www.adobe.com/products/dng/).

Some day even CS5 will be outdated and probably face the problem as CS4 already does. Some RAW Formats are available for the latest ACR versions only. But to update ACR you need a newer CS version and so on... DNG Converter is always up to date, hence .dng files can be edited with older CS versions even if you have the latest camera models.